# How to consume a web service with headers C #?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Looking at the application of postman, I wanted to know if it is possible by means of code, consume a web service with headers.
This is an example of how consuming a web service with header of postman.

[image]

I would like to consume the same web service but by means of code.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add request headers with WebClient C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596417/add-request-headers-with-webclient-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
 public static string getResponseFromwebService(string serviceUrl)
    {

        var baseurl = "http://localhost:1936/";
        var auth= "123456";
        var apid = "1";

        var requestUrl = baseurl + serviceUrl;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorisation", auth);
        request.Headers.Add("appId", apid);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

You'd want to keep the variables in some config, and probably serialize the response to objects of sorts.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I needed, when you are new to the language c # there are things you do not know and help like yours is very useful.

Comment: Glad to help. It's true, that this is just another answer to the same question asked before. But I have been in the same situation, and sometimes that other answer just slightly different makes more sense